# Eclipse RAP/RCP Server push/callback

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-rap

I am building a message application.. in which the UI should get notified when the new message come in the system...

What is best way to achieve it?..

One way is to create a background task that will poll server every one minute to see if there are any new messages in last one minute..
If this is the case then, where would this code of polling should go?.. because.. this task should be initiated every time user logs in into the system.

Is there any other way through which server will notify the UI as and when there are new messages in the system and UI will refresh itself to show some animation to depict that there are new messages in the system..

Answer (score 0):

As of the current RAP version (2.3) you are able to push updates from the server to the client. Your weapon of choice would be `ServerPushSession`.

For more information and example code see the [RAP developer guide on "Server Push"](http://eclipse.org/rap/developers-guide/devguide.php?topic=server-push.html&version=2.3) .